# Can't suppress messages in blogdown/knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-leaflet

Here is a [blog](https://lpdata.me/post/leaflet-map/) post created with blogdown

The R chunk of code begins with

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
````

However, three messages appear each time I read a shapefile using `sf::st_read`

How do I prevent these messages from appearing in the post?

Does the answer lie in [this](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/) page about knitr options?

Comment: I think `st_read` is just printing output normally, this won't be affected by `message = FALSE` or `warning = FALSE`. If you don't need any output from the chunk you can do `results = 'hide'` in the chunk options, otherwise I think you can stop it printing using `st_read(..., quiet = TRUE)`

Comment: That did the trick. Thank-you.

Answer (score 14):

<sub>*Moving an apparent solution initially posted in the comments to a full answer. Reasoning outlined [in this meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/6296561)*</sub>

> I think `st_read` is just printing output normally, this won't be affected by `message = FALSE` or `warning = FALSE`. If you don't need any output from the chunk you can do `results = 'hide'` in the chunk options, otherwise I think you can stop it printing using `st_read(..., quiet = TRUE)`

Originally posted by [Marius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222578/marius) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50479535/cant-suppress-messages-in-blogdown-knitr/57638631#comment87973732_50479535)